# MultiSelect ListBox alters options when switching windows in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a problem with MultiSelect ListBox in VBA (Excel). I want a user to choose several options in the ListBox but he also needs to be able to switch windows in the meantime to look up the choices in another program. The problem happens when user switches the window and returns to Excel. When he selects an option then the option, that was selected as the last before switching the windows, alters the state (if the last action was select, the option gets unselected; if the last action was unselect, the option gets selected).

Example

[image: example]

I choose A and B. I switch the window and then return to Excel. I click on D and B gets unselected (the last chosen option before switching the windows). It is really confusing for the user.

Anyone has idea what is the cause of this problem? Is there a way to fix this?

All ListBox code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

  Worksheets(1).ListBox1.Clear

  ile = Worksheets(2).Range("b1").Value

  For i = 1 To ile
    Worksheets(1).ListBox1.AddItem (Worksheets(2).Range("b" + CStr(i + 2)))
  Next i

End Sub


Private Sub ListBox1_GotFocus()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Range("a1").Select

End Sub
```

Focus disappears but the problem is not fixed

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHd9e.jpg

Comment: Is there any code that's written when either the window or the listbox is focused?

Comment: is it really being deselected, or it it just the highlighting that is wrong?

Comment: at shahkalpesh
There is code:
Private Sub ListBox1_GotFocus()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range("a1").Select
End Sub
focus disappears but the problem is not fixed

| at Sean Cheshire
The highlighted options are really selected, so the highlighting is right.

Comment: Can you supply any more of your code to help? There are a number of places the selection can be changed, even on code outside the form code (i.e. from the code that calls/shows the form, etc.), depending on how you've set everything up.

Answer (score 0):

another weird behavior of excel right there

you can store the users selection in some obscure range of some worksheet that
you don't likely use (like sheet3) so when it goes out of focus, it doesn't forget
what was selected

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    Dim i As Long, ii As Long
    With Sheet3.[ObscureRange]
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.listCount - 1
            If ListBox1.Selected(i) = False Then
            For ii = 1 To 250
                If ListBox1.List(i) = .Offset(ii, 0) Then _
                .Offset(ii, 0).Delete xlShiftUp
            If "" = .Offset(ii, 0) Then Exit For
            Next
            Else
            For ii = 1 To 250
                If XcludeList(ListBox1.List(i)) = False Then _
                If "" = .Offset(ii, 0) Then _
                .Offset(ii, 0) = ListBox1.List(i): Exit For
            Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

XcludeList Sub

```
Function XcludeList(strVal As String) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheet3.[ObscureRange]
    For i = 1 To 250
        If strVal = .Offset(i, 0) Then XcludeList = True: Exit For
        If .Offset(i, 0).Value = "" Then XcludeList = False: Exit For
    Next
    End With
End Function
```

another advantage of this is that it still remembers the selections after the user closes the userform, if you consider it an advantage :D